# Trigger Anchor Tag with LinkButton onclick function vb.net

Tags: onclick, anchor, datalist, linkbutton

as you know, Fancybox comes with the  anchor tag
I am currently working on a project of a datalist using vb.net
When I click the Linkbutton, I am suppose to get the command argument and set it to session and then open up the fancybox. As fancybox has its own restriction to anchor tags, it is only workable on the first item of the datalist
So I want to do it in such a way that when I click the linkbutton, I will pass the session and also trigger the anchor tag from the code behind. Here is the codebehind for the button_click for the linkbutton

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)


    'Dim addJobRequest As Button = sender
    ' Dim jobID As String = addJobRequest.CommandArgument
    ' addJobtoRequest(jobID)

    Dim button As LinkButton = sender
    Dim itegerr As Integer = button.CommandArgument
    Session("jobID") = itegerr
    Return
    'From here, I need a code that can trigger anchor tag

End Sub
```

Here is the code for the anchor tag

```
<a id="fancybox-manual-b" href="javascript:;">
```

P.s. I have tried the linkbutton href function and but it doesn't work.